# Toolbar in custom page template

Tags: template, pagination

i need add custom page template toolbar with sort by and pagination, because my template custom page shows a list of sub-categories in this category and need add pagination with sorting

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [the link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16957/create-magento-pagination-in-custom-product-collection-inside-phtml-file)

in this creating pager for products. Please adopt for your need i.e for category.

Please share your code even if facing issues.