# set a product list with pager in ajax action controller

Tags: product-list, ajax, pager

I am trying to set child to another block using the following script :

```
public function refreshlistAction() {
    $data = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    if (isset($data['delivery'])) {
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
        $blockPager = $layout->createBlock('page/html_pager','product_list_toolbar_pager');
        $blockToolbar = $layout->createBlock('catalog/product_list_toolbar', 'product_list_toolbar')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml');
        $blockToolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager',$blockPager);
        $block = $layout->createBlock('catalog/product_list', 'product_box_list')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');
        $block->setChild('toolbar', $blockToolbar);
        $block->setCategoryId($data['category']);
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        //let's check if there is not a delivery mode set and a product in the cart
        if (($session->hasDelivery())&&(!empty($session->getDelivery()))&&(!empty(Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getProductIds()))&&($session->getDelivery()!=$data['delivery'])){
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice($this->__("Your cart is not empty. Therefore, you cannot adopt a different delivery mode"));
            $data['delivery'] = $session->getDelivery();
        }
        $block->setFilterDelivery($data['delivery']);
        $session->setDelivery($data['delivery']);
        $html = $block->toHtml();
        $this->getResponse()
                ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
                ->setBody($html);
        return;
    } else {
        echo $this->__('This page cannot be accessed');
    }
}
```

The product list and toolbar are returned and can be displayed but the pager is not. If I make a var_dump in toolbar.php(line 809) :

```
$pagerBlock = $this->getChild('product_list_toolbar_pager');
var_dump($pagerBlock);
```

$pagerBlock contains a boolean (false).

Is there something I am missing ?

My idea is to refresh the product list with ajax on an attribute filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I was going little bit the wrong way. I overrode the c`atalog/product_list` to fit to this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/16958/9489, I did not need to reload toolbars or so on and it works like a charm.